# Internationalization is not working in Spring Boot v2.3.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, internationalization

I'm trying to implement Internationalization in Spring boot. I have configured a configuration class, message.properties and its jsp implementation like below. But it is not working in runtime. When i check the chrome browser debugger, it seems to redirect my Internationalization URL to default url always.

Below are the structure of my application

**Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer { 

    @Bean
       public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
            SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
            localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
            return  localeResolver;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
            LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
            localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
            return localeChangeInterceptor;
        }

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
            registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());//.addPathPatterns("/*");
        }
    
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource   messageSource()
    {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:locale/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600); //refresh once per hour
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

messages.properties files are under src/main/resources package ->locale folder

**messages.properties**

```
#login page
title.login.page=Login Page
label.login.header=Login To Your Account
```

**messages_fr.properties**

```
#login page
title.login.page=Page de connexion
label.login.header=Connectez-vous à votre compte
```

**.jsp Page**

```
<title><spring:message code="title.login.page"/></title>
<spring:message code="label.login.header"/>
```

It is redirecting my url when i enter

```
http://localhost:8080/****/user/login?lang=fr
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/****/user/login
```

And Language translation is not happening. Assist me on this!

Comment: WIld guess this is a Spring Security login page?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes it is.

Comment: Before login, spring internalization not working (for me).